# Scrapy - saving links while following them

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm pretty new to Python and Scrapy and I think that the answer should be quite simple but having hard time figuring this out myself. The code takes all links, follows them and records the title of the article. How do I pass url that I get to my item? I want to save the shortlink it uses with the article title. Thank you

```
def parse(self, response):
    for url in response.xpath("//li[@id]/@data-shortlink").extract():
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.get_details)

def get_details(self, response):
        article = ArticleItem()
        article['title'] = response.xpath("//h1/text()").extract()
        yield article
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's contained within the [`Response()` object](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response), you can use `response.url` to get the URL:

```
def get_details(self, response):
        article = ArticleItem()
        article['title'] = response.xpath("//h1/text()").extract()
        article['url'] = response.url
        yield article
```

Comment: works great. is there a way to get it copy short links i feed to parse and not the full links it actually follows?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest.  I suggest experimenting and `print()`ing out the different [Response subclass methods](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-response-subclasses).  Alternatively if it's an arg you feed to parse() then it seems you should certainly also be able to pass it to get_details...